# Posting object in ASP.NET MVC API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have an **MVC application**, that contains a web application in a simple **mvc 4 project**.
Moreover I have a *Windows application*, that is a windows execution of the web application in an other windows application project.

The Windows application uses **MVC API** and makes calls to the MVC Web Application Controller by the name of TfsApiController by a resthelper class.

All the methods are working except the post method. I want to post an object to the tfsapi controller.

The post method of rest helper class:

```
public void Post(T targetObject)
{
    if (targetObject == null)
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentNullException("targetObject");
    }

    //Get formatting details.
    System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter myFormatter = new XmlMediaTypeFormatter();

    myUrlSuffix = "api/tfsapi";

    //Make the call.
    var result = this.MainHttpClient.PostAsync(myUrlSuffix, targetObject, myFormatter).Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
}
```

My TfsApiController method:

```
public void PostPreActivity(PreActivity preActivity)
{
}
```

And the Routing:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "PostPreActivity",
routeTemplate: "api/tfsapi/Post",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
).RouteHandler = new SessionRouteHandler();
```

I wasted lot of hours, but i do not know what is the problem.

UPDATE:

This is my all routings:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "GetWorkItemsByProject",
         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{projectID}",
         defaults: new { controller = "tfsapi", action = "GetWorkItems", projectID = UrlParameter.Optional }
     ).RouteHandler = new SessionRouteHandler();;

RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "ActionWebApiRoute",
         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
     ).RouteHandler = new SessionRouteHandler();

RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "DefaultApi",
         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
         defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
     ).RouteHandler = new SessionRouteHandler();
```

Answer (score 0):

You route seems to be incorrect, change it to something like below and try again:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "TfsApiRoute",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

by the way, what are you using SessionRouteHandler for?

[**Update after the post update above**]

You need to change the following code to include the action name completely:
myUrlSuffix = "api/tfsapi/**PostPreActivity**";

I believe this is because based on your updated routings,when a request like 'api/tfsapi' comes, it would be tried to be matched against the 1st route with the name "GetWorkItemsByProject" and since 'action' is not optional here, you are probably seeing 404 not found.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this routing is my default routing. I have updated the post.

Comment: I have updated my post above based on your routing update. let me know if this helps.